# ExtJS6: call panel with store with extra parameters

Tags: extjs, extjs6

I have Panel, which I call like so:

```
var relationshipsPanel = Ext.create('Test.view.RelationshipsPanel'); // ?store parameters?
Ext.getCmp('mainTabPanel').add(relationshipsPanel);
```

And Panel has store:

```
...
proxy: {
    type: 'ajax',
    api: {
        read: '_crud/tree_relationships.php?act=read' // &id_object=123
    },
    reader: {
        type: 'json'
    }
}
...
```

Store in Panel declared with id:

```
Ext.define('Test.view.RelationshipsPanel', {
    extend: 'Ext.panel.Panel',
    alias: 'widget.relationshipspanel',

    id: 'relationshipsPanel',
    itemId: 'relationshipsPanel'

    items: [
        {
            xtype: 'treepanel',
            scrollable: true,
            autoLoad: true,
            store: 'relationships', // store id
            columns: [
                ...
            ]
        }
    ]

});
```

And the store itself is declared in the application:

```
Ext.application({
...
    stores: [
        'relationships'
    ]
...
```

I want to set store parameter `id_object=123`. So in the end, the API query `read` should look like this: `_crud/tree_relationships.php?act=read&id_object=123`

How to call Panel with store with GET extra parameters?

Comment: Why only post half the code? How is the store defined in your custom class?

Comment: @EvanTrimboli , thank you. Added to the question.

Comment: That particular store is shared across the entire app, so it's not really relevant.

Comment: Okay, then I'll move store to the panel. How to call a panel with store parameters?

Answer (score 1):

**Ext.data.proxy.Proxy** internally uses **Ext.data.Connection** which allows extraParams to send additional parameters.

You can use if store is being created dynamically or inside init method:

```
proxy: {
  type: 'ajax',
  api: {
    read: '_crud/tree_relationships.php?act=read' // &id_object=123
  },
  reader: {
      type: 'json'
  },
  extraParams: {
    id_object: 123
  }
}
```

If you want to load store with params:

```
store.load({params: { id_object: 123 }});
```

or you can do inside init method:

```
store.getProxy().setExtraParams({id_object: 123});
```

**Sencha Fiddle:** https://fiddle.sencha.com/#fiddle/2931&view/editor

**Store Docs:** http://docs.sencha.com/extjs/6.0.1/modern/Ext.data.Store.html

**Connection Docs:** http://docs.sencha.com/extjs/6.0.1/classic/Ext.data.Connection.html#cfg-extraParams

Comment: Did I understand correctly that in order to call the Panel with the extra store params, I need to create store with `Ext.Create` and need to create Panel with `Ext.Create`? And I can't do something like `Ext.create('Test.view.RelationshipsPanel', [store.load({params: { id_object: 123 }})]);`?